# How do I send a hosted PDF via an email intent?

Tags: android, email, pdf, android-intent

I am trying to send a pdf that is hosted via an email intent.

```
    Intent launchEmailClientIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    launchEmailClientIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    launchEmailClientIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    launchEmailClientIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    launchEmailClientIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(template));
    launchEmailClientIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf"));
    this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(launchEmailClientIntent, ""), requestCode);
```

But when the mail client opens it says that it "Can't attach empty file"
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes. You cannot attach a file that is on the web. You can only attach files that are on your device.

Comment: But why not just send the url in the email text? I hate it when people send me files instead of a link.

Comment: @greenapps BR. Thank you. I will look at possibly downloading the file and attaching it.